# Cocoa OS X graphs (bar and line graph) libraries?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

Are there any Cocoa OS X graphs (bar and line graph) libraries avaible for Objective-C? I've found only for iOS but none for OS X.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I haven't looked for these before, but with a basic google search I found https://github.com/ChimpStudios/AmCharts

Comment: Take a look at CorePlot, its based on Core Animation and works on both OS X and ios.